# Creating an efficient development enviroment + workflow for dApp development

Tags: contract-development, dapp-development, contract-debugging, testnets

What I want to do is create an efficient workflow for rapidly developing, and testing dapps on different chains LOCALLY.

I thought about using Remix IDE, with testing environments for each respective chain.

Right of the bat, i noticed different problems

- Remix IDE is somehow incapable of deploying multiple contracts together. Or really just handling more than one .sol file at any given point. Don't know what the point of the program is then, but I'd consider it useless.
- Metamask really doesn't want to work with your local test net environment.

But what seems to be a way bigger problem are the multitude of js frameworks, the individual tools written for them and their respective incompatibility. I want to build my workflow in a way that anybody can send me their project and I can test it locally without much effort.

How do I do this?

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps you should consider using [Hardhat](https://hardhat.org/tutorial/testing-contracts.html). It may be challenging to learn it at first but it comes with amazing plugins for deploying contract, debugging, checking transaction price, ...

Comment: after writing this, i discovered that hardhat is actually compatible with ganache, which i thought it wasn't. What if I don't wanna use ANY js framework tho? I find it incredibly distracting.

Comment: I realized this is way outside the scope of a normal SE question. Maybe we should continue this in a chat?